# Django query on empty related_set

Tags: django, left-join

I have two models with a 1-to-Many relationship - parent and child. I want to query all parents with no children. In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM parent p
    LEFT JOIN children c on (p.id=c.parent_id)
WHERE c.id IS NULL
```

How can I do the same with a single Django query?

The relevant parts of the model are:

```
class Parent(model):
    ...

class Child(model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
```

Comment: can you provide the code for your models?

Comment: Provided the relevant bit. It's trivial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) field lookup, which:

> Takes either **True** or **False**, which correspond to SQL queries of **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL**, respectively.

Thus, the queryset will look like the following:

`Parent.objects.filter(children__isnull=True)`

Comment: For those like me who are looking for the exact opposite, bear in mind that `Parent.objects.filter(children__isnull=False)` works, but can cause duplicates in the queryset. Add `.distinct()` after the filter to avoid this.

Comment: @Shovalt you can also consider `Parent.objects.exclude(children__isnull=True)`. Regarding duplicates, that solely depends on your data model and what you are storing in the Parent table.